# Owl slider shows three items instead of one in responsive mobile mode

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, owl-carousel

I have following call to owl carousel. I have tried everything I can and search the web whole a lot but couldn't find the fix. I have tried updating latest css/js this didn't help me. Please check the screenshots as well. On their official site issue randomly reproduced as well.

Any help would be great I have wasted tons of hours on this. Note that this issue is specifically observed on iPhone 6 and decedents.

```
$('#Owl-demo').owlCarousel({
            loop: true,
            margin: 10,
            responsiveClass: true,
            responsive: {
                0: {
                    items: 1,
                    nav: true
                },
                600: {
                    items: 2,
                    nav: false
                },
                1000: {
                    items: 3,
                    nav: true,
                    loop: false
                }
            }
        });
```

[image]

Also plugin live site (randomly) reproduced.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Sounds like this is an issue with the owl carousel plugin code and won't be fixed without diving into their code.

Comment: Thank @realseanp I am able to fix pretty much. Once done I will share with you.

Comment: Could you take screenshots after you've reloaded the page to remove the "You might need to reload the page for proper user agent spoofing and viewport rendering" message? I suspect the issue is due to your css, not owl slider.

Comment: There was problem with loading images as there size was too big for mobile devices therefore, they have rendering issue. There are couple of solutions to this problem, either use .load instead of ready or use lazyloading. I have used .load and it has fixed my issue. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was problem with loading images as there size was too big for mobile devices therefore, they have rendering issue.

There are couple of solutions to this problem, either use `.load` instead of `.ready` or use lazy loading. I have used `.load` and it has fixed my issue.